# Анализ email адреса с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как из `name@mail.ru` получить только **name** с помощью регулярного выражения?

Comment: `preg_match('/^[^@]+/', $email, $match);` И зачем регулярные выражения, если можно через [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php) найти знак *@* и получить строку до этого знака? Т.е. как-то так: `substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'))`

Comment: @Ворон, действительно. Вот нашел очень удобную реализацию.

`function after ($this, $inthat)
{
 if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this)))
 return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$this)+strlen($this));
};`

Comment: Можно еще через [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php): `explode('@', $email)` - и выбираете первую часть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
.*(?=@)
```

Comment: корректнее, [вероятно](http://ideone.com/CigXeo), `.+(?=@)`, ведь имя не может быть пустым.

Comment: @Sergiks, если исходная строка корректна, то получится одно и то же. Если нет, то оба варианта не годятся :)

Comment: обратная сторона test driven development? =)

Answer (score 0):

```
list($name,) = explode('@',$email);
```

вот безошибочный вариант, но не проверяет, что же на входе.

Для проверки валидности email адресов есть многострочная регулярка (http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), но это перебор. Если действительно хочется реального адреса - лучше отправлять письмо с подтверждением

Comment: ошибка случится, если подадут некорректный адрес.